# OnClick in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

This is my activity.I have created a list view and it fetches the data from database and display in list view.I want to click a item in listview so that the details corresponding to that item will be displayed in another layout with the data from database can anyone help with the next step

*

Answer (score 1):

```
    vehList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            //write your code here
        }
    });
```